# Unable to concatenate two arrays inside two arrays without duplicate

Tags: javascript

So I have two arrays of data `data.SensorData` and `state.SensorData`
they contain similar sensors information, however `data.SensorData` always get new Events `data.SensorData[i].Events` and I would like to concatenate the two Events without having duplicate events

here is the code I wrote

```
      console.log(state.sensorData[0].Events.length);//50
      for (let i = 1; i < data.SensorData.length; i++) {
        console.log("<...");
        data.SensorData[i].Events = data.SensorData[i]?.Events.concat(
          state.sensorData[i]?.Events
        );
      }
      //should be 100 events but it stays 50
      console.log(state.sensorData[0].Events.length);//50
```

Basically, they are not concatenating.

The JSON looks like this

```
[
{SensorID: 1, BatteryPct: 100, LastActiveTime: 1656461958000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 2, BatteryPct: 80, LastActiveTime: 1656461593000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 3, BatteryPct: 80, LastActiveTime: 1656462563000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 4, BatteryPct: 80, LastActiveTime: 1656462563000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 5, BatteryPct: 42, LastActiveTime: 1656424819000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 6, BatteryPct: null, LastActiveTime: 1656318675000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 7, BatteryPct: null, LastActiveTime: 1656253855000, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(50)}
{SensorID: 8, BatteryPct: 80, LastActiveTime: 1656447026000, LastStatus: 'OFFLINE', Events: Array(50)}
]
```

Comment: There seems to be no change in `state.sensorData[0]` in the code.

Comment: show your JSON files

Comment: Your code assumes that `data` and `state` contain _the same_ list, not just contain lists with the same kind of information. So: do they? Is there any reason to assume that the 12th element in `data.SensorData` is also the 12th element in `data.SensorData`?

Comment: Your code assigns the concatenated array to `data.SensorData[i].Events`, so why would you expect `state.sensorData[0].Events` to change?

Comment: @Bergi I expect data.SensorData[i].Events to change

Comment: @YujinDong But that's not what you are logging in the end.

Comment: Please do not completely replace your question with a different one, especially after it has attracted comments and answers. If you have another question, please [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Corrections

1. You have a wrong variable name in the `state.sensorData[i]?.Events` inside the `concat` method

```js
data.SensorData[i].Events = data.SensorData[i]?.Events.concat(
          state.sensorData[i]?.Events
        );
```

It should be capital 'S' in `state.SensorData[i]?.Events`

```js
data.SensorData[i].Events = data.SensorData[i]?.Events.concat(
          state.SensorData[i]?.Events
        );
```

2. You are also starting the array from the first index rather than zero index, while printing the zero index element

```
for (let i = 1...
```

should be

```
for (let i = 0...
```

### Solution

The `concat` method does not remove duplicates, as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

You need to remove them your self. To do so you can use a function like

```js
function removeDuplicatesFromArray(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j]) // Check here against whatever your unique value is
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

so your code would eventually become

```js
console.log(state.sensorData[0].Events.length);//50
      for (let i = 0; i < data.SensorData.length; i++) {
        console.log("<...");
        data.SensorData[i].Events = removeDuplicatesFromArray(data.SensorData[i]?.Events.concat(
          state.SensorData[i]?.Events
        ));
      }
      //should be 100 events but it stays 50
      console.log(state.sensorData[0].Events.length);//50
```

### Running Example

```js
function removeDuplicatesFromArray(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j]) // Check here against whatever your unique value is
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

var SensorData = [
{"SensorID": 1, "BatteryPct": 100, "LastActiveTime": 1656461958000, "LastStatus": "ONLINE", "Events": [1,2,3,4]},
{"SensorID": 1, "BatteryPct": 100, "LastActiveTime": 1656461958000, "LastStatus": "ONLINE", "Events": [1,2,3,4]}
];

var NewSensorData = [
{"SensorID": 1, "BatteryPct": 100, "LastActiveTime": 1656461958000, "LastStatus": "ONLINE", "Events": [1,2,3,4,5]},
{"SensorID": 1, "BatteryPct": 100, "LastActiveTime": 1656461958000, "LastStatus": "ONLINE", "Events": [1,2,3,4,7,8]}
];

console.log("Old Events Values");
SensorData.forEach((x) => console.log(x.Events));
for (let i = 0; i < SensorData.length; i++) {
  SensorData[i].Events = removeDuplicatesFromArray(SensorData[i].Events.concat(
    NewSensorData[i].Events
  ));
}
console.log("New Events Values");
SensorData.forEach((x) => console.log(x.Events));
```

Comment: sorry it already is, those 1,2,.... showed up because I did copy past from print on the browser and usually it adds those.

Comment: Aha, got it. I have updated my answer, it seems you have a type in the `concat` method to access the new `Events`

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a running example as well as explanation, let me know if that works out for you.

Answer (score -1):

[Eagnir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14103833/eagnir)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794820) is a good way to go about it coding your own duplicate filter function. You can also use javascript's built in hashset object to construct an set of unique values from your two arrays, then convert it back to an array.

For this solution, I've assumed that your `state.sensorData` will be a unique object because I'm not sure if you will always get a 1-to-1 match between your `state` and your `data` objects. You would then just modify the below code to nest another for-loop.

Running example (scroll to bottom to see solution):

```js
let data = {
  SensorData: [
    {
      SensorID: 1,
      BatteryPct: 100,
      LastActiveTime: 1656461958000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 2,
      BatteryPct: 80,
      LastActiveTime: 1656461593000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 3,
      BatteryPct: 80,
      LastActiveTime: 1656462563000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 4,
      BatteryPct: 80,
      LastActiveTime: 1656462563000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 5,
      BatteryPct: 42,
      LastActiveTime: 1656424819000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 6,
      BatteryPct: null,
      LastActiveTime: 1656318675000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 7,
      BatteryPct: null,
      LastActiveTime: 1656253855000,
      LastStatus: 'ONLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
    {
      SensorID: 8,
      BatteryPct: 80,
      LastActiveTime: 1656447026000,
      LastStatus: 'OFFLINE',
      Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)),
    },
  ],
};

const state = {
  sensorData: {
    Events: Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)),
  },
};

console.log(data.SensorData[0].Events.length); //50
for (let i = 0; i < data.SensorData.length; i++) {
  let hashSet = new Set();
  data.SensorData[i].Events.forEach((e) => hashSet.add(e));
  state.sensorData.Events.forEach((e) => hashSet.add(e));
  data.SensorData[i].Events = Array.from(hashSet);
}

//should be 100 events but it stays 50
console.log(data.SensorData[0].Events.length); //100
```